# Is there a way to tell if my computer camera is on with javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, camera, getusermedia

I'm using getUserMedia to take pictures using my computer's camera and I need to do a check to determine if the computer's camera is on before continuing through my application.

Is there a way to determine if my computer's camera is on using javascript?

Comment: You have a success callback when you call `getUserMedia`. Just access that stream object and check if there are video tracks...

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.
As you may know, getUserMedia has a success callback; it's first parameter is the media stream.
If you store the stream into a variable and check if the variable exists/has a value, then you have a stream, so obviously the camera must be on.

```
getUserMedia({video:true},function(stream){
    window.stream = stream;
    //we have a stream now, so the device is on
},function(){alert("Error!");}
```